# http to https and redirect to folder appending php extension through .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to get `http: //domain.com/keyword` and redirect to `https: //domain.com/folder/keyword.php` via .htaccess

Note that I need to resolve 4 steps here:

- redirect www to non-www
- redirect http to https
- redirect from domain root to domain/folder
- append .php to keyword

Thank you in advance.

I tried to mix several codes together but with no sucess. Anyone could help me I will thank you a lot!

Comment: "redirect to folder appending php extension" - I would think this should be an internal "rewrite", not a "redirect"? You appear to be using the term "redirect" for both. In other words, `https://example.com/keyword` should be what the user sees in the browser's address bar?

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that you want all `http` requests redirected to `https`, all requests to a hostname other than `example.com` to be redirected to `example.com`, and to serve keywords from a PHP file in `/folder/`... I think your best option is going to be this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /folder/$1.php
```

First rule: if the `http:` transport is used, results in one redirect via the browser to `https://example.com`. This runs no matter what the hostname is, so captures any hostname that reaches the site (such as `www.example.com`). This forces the secure transport for the response traffic and reduces the cases in which the second rule needs to run.

Second rule: if we already have `https` transport (because of the first rule) and not the correct hostname of `example.com`, results in a browser redirect to `https://example.com`.

These first two rules trigger browser-side redirects since we are changing the transport and/or the hostname. The `301` status codes for redirects are a suggestion. I think you should do this at least for the http->https as you probably want any links out there that have a non-secure transport to be updated to point to the secure transport. If you don't want to permanently redirect [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to example.com, then change the second rule to a `302` status code.

Third and fourth rules: if the URI given does not resolve to something present, and is not a reference to something in the `/folder/` path, we then rewrite the path internally to get to the files we want (in this case, the .php file with the same prefix). This rule does not trigger a browser-side redirect, so does not expose the rewrite to the remote user.

Comment: Great! By the way, how to redirect it with url parameters? Exemple from 'http: //domain.com/keyword/?tag=new' to redirect to 'https: //domain.com/folder/keyword.php?tag=new' ??? This is because when link is shared in whatsapp it appends a lot of data in url parameter.

Comment: by the way, url parameters may vary to any name and value. Example: ?tag=abc or ?anyothername=anyothervalue

Comment: I did notice the problem may be in the slash at the end of original url. If I enter 'https: //example.com/username/' (with slash at end) it now works, but without the slash it works.

Comment: I've updated the rules to support both the original spec and with a trailing slash. The query parameters work okay in my tests, being moved to the end of the path automatically.

Comment: @lbdv "how to redirect it with url parameters?" - The existing rules would already redirect any URL parameters - this is the default behaviour, you do not need to do anything special with respect to URL parameters (ie. the query string). "the problem may be in the slash at the end of original url" - The example URL in your question does not include a trailing slash? These are two different URLs - you should not serve the same resource from both URLs (slash vs no-slash) as this potentially creates a duplicate content issue. So, do your canonical URLs end in a slash or not?

Comment: @ricardkelly The www to non-www redirect is in the wrong place and would expose the rewritten URL (it's also an implied 302, as opposed to a 301).

Comment: @MrWhite good point - fixed the error. That crept in with an earlier edit to reduce the redirects, but the redirect is needed in this case.